# Correct terminology for Dead Man Switch

Tags: amazon-s3

I've implemented a Dead Man Switch this way:

A script can be fired by an event. When the script starts it looks for a specific object on an S3 bucket. If that object can't be found for any reason (be it network issues to access the bucket, lack of permissions, the object was removed or any other reason) then the script will abort before doing any other actions.

I suppose this is a classic Dead Man Switch.

The idea is to let us remove this object in case we need to stop the script in an emergency.

My question is about terminology - I also supply a script to our team to create or remove that S3 object. I want it to be clear which actions means what (remove object - stop script from doing anything, create object - let the script continue with its work). I used "removed" and "reinstate" and was told this is too ambiguous. I now contemplate about "pushed" and "enabled" but this too sounds too vague. I'm also thinking about "pulled" (object removed) vs. "rearmed" (object created).

It's important that the terminology will be clear since if this script is used then this is expected to happen during emergency, so we want to minimize confusion as much as possible.

I suppose the problem is the inherent "double negative".

So far I didn't find any common name used to describe these actions. Wikipedia and other places describe what the switch is, but not actions of enabling or disabling it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the system would be:

- **Enabled** if the object is present
- **Disabled** if the object is absent

Placing the object would **enable** the script.

Removing (deleting) the object would **disable** the script.

You could even call the file *enable-xxx-script* to make it more obvious.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. Will use this.